# google.maps.LatLng returns a function which returns 'a'. Why?

Tags: javascript, function, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, return

I created a function to draw multiple markers from an object on a map. Each marker gets also pushed in an array to access it later.

My createMarker function looks like this and gets called in the initMap function:

```
function createMarker(markerData){
for(var i = 0; i < markerData.length; i++){

    var testing = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markerData[i].lat), parseFloat(markerData[i].lng));

    console.log(testing);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markerData[i].lat), parseFloat(markerData[i].lng)),
        map: myMap
    });

    markerBounds.extend(marker.position);
    markerArray.push(marker);
}
```

}

But my problem is, that the console log only returns:

```
function (){return a}
```

and not the expected lat lng object. So in my markerArray there are no lat lng coordinates also. But the markers are still created on the map.

Later I want to compare each marker position from markerArray with the current user position. But I think this isn't working, because the problem described above.

```
for (var i = 0; i < markerArray.length; i++) {
    var markerPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markerArray[i].lat), parseFloat(markerArray[i].lng));
    if(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(userPosition, markerPosition) < radius){
        console.log('test');
    }
}
```

I did a research on this but could not find an answer. The only info I got is about asynchronous functions.

I hope you can understand the problem. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I could not reproduce your problem, but my bet is, that you have some misconceptions about what do you put in the array and which the properties of the Objects are. Let me clear it:

1. In the LatLng object the `lat` and `lng` are getter functions, which means, that you should call, for example position.lat() to get the Lat coordinate in Float.
2. The Marker object has a `position` property, which is a LatLng object.
   So if you want, for example the Latitude of a marker: `myMarker.position.lat()`

In your code you put markers in the array, but at the distance calculation, you expects positions:

So here is some working example, i hope it helps:

```
    var myMarkerData = [{lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644}, {lat: -34.396, lng: 150.643}]
    var markerArray = []
    var userPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.398, 150.645);
    function createMarker(markerData){
        for(var i = 0; i < markerData.length; i++){

            var testing = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markerData[i].lat), parseFloat(markerData[i].lng));
            console.log(testing);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markerData[i].lat), parseFloat(markerData[i].lng)),
                map: map
            });
            //markerBounds.extend(marker.position);
            markerArray.push(marker);
        }
    }
      var map;
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 8,
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644}
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
            mapOptions);

        createMarker(myMarkerData)
        for (var i = 0; i < markerArray.length; i++) {
                //var markerPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markerArray[i].position.lat()), parseFloat(markerArray[i].position.lng()));
                var markerPosition = markerArray[i].position
                console.log(markerPosition,userPosition)
                var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(userPosition, markerPosition)
                console.log(distance)
        }
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You gave me the decisive tip. My problem was, that I did not use lat and lng as getter functions. With .position.lat() I get the correct values.

Comment: +1 because you gave me the right hint. I triggered the OP issue with this: Firstly, I was using the https:// method to get the address information for an address. Here it was `results [0].geometry.location.lat;`. Then I changed it to the API call and here it changed to `.geometry.location.lat();